# Regular expresstion to match word followed by space or empty

Tags: regex

i want to match this following string

```
<div class="Step A2aModalStep Modal">
<div class="A2aModalStep Step Modal">
```

i tried this one `<div class=\"[|\w*\s]*A2aModalStep.*` but it matched only first one

and this one `<div class=\"*.A2aModalStep.*` only match with 2nd line code...

i want to match both

Comment: Can you please post what your expected result would look like?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "followed by … empty"?

Comment: @AndreasPizsa solved it, here is the final code <div class=\"[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]*\s[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]*\s[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]*\"> not in a perfect shape, but working good

Comment: Oh wow, that’s pretty bad. But I’m glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Keep going to capture the whole div, and add in `?.*` for other possible attributes:

```js
const re = /<div ?.* class=["|'][\w\s]*A2aModalStep[\w\s]*["|']?.*>/
const arr = [
    `<div class="Step A2aModalStep Modal">`,
    `<div class="A2aModalStep Step Modal">`,
    `<div id="a" class="A2aModalStep Step Modal">`,
    `<div class='A2aModalStep Step Modal'>`,
    `<div id='a' class='Step Modal' data-attr='b'>`,
    `<div id='a' class='A2aModalStep Step Modal' data-attr='b'>`,
]

const res = arr.map(el => el.match(re) ? "match" : "no match")

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this https://regex101.com/r/M31WYn/1/

```
<div class="(Step )?A2aModalStep.*>
```

Comment: cant use wildcard as it matches other big classes...

i want the first term as Step or empty followed by A2aModalStep

Comment: <div class=\"[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]\s[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]\s[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]">
can you help me to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

workaround solution

```
<div class=\"[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]*\s[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]*\s[A2aModalStep|Step|Model]*\">
```